# How to pronounce bechamel the English way?

Tags: pronunciation, french

I had an argument with my friend the other day about the pronunciation of *bechamel*.

Everyone I know is pronouncing it like *besha-mel*. I've looked it up though and found out that the correct pronunciation is *bay-shah-mel* (according to [Cambridge](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/pronunciation/english/bechamel)), which reports that the word derives from French. However, I've been told that if pronounced the English way it would sound like the former *beh-shah-mel* with the 'sh' sound, which I do not agree with since I'd pronounce *bech*- with a 'k' sound.

As far as I'm concerned there's no rule regarding this; it's one of those things you have to learn and memorise (see [this thread](https://forum.wordreference.com/threads/why-does-ch-sounds-like-k.2352341)), but I'd like to know if the English (incorrect) pronunciation of *bechamel* would sound like *beh-cah-mel* with the 'k' sound or the previously mentioned 'sh' sound.

Comment: I've always pronounced it the way you don't like—and that's how I've most commonly heard it pronounced. For the people living here (Canada for me—I'm not sure about Quebec, specifically), it *is* the "correct" pronunciation. (What's "correct" is relative.)

Comment: Pronouncing it like the name of the guy who perfected the sauce, Louis de Béchamel, could hardly be called 'incorrect'.

Comment: You can’t talk about how a word is pronounced using its spellings. You have to use phonetic notation. [Wiktionary’s *béchamel* entry](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/b%C3%A9chamel#English) gives both French and British pronunciations using standard phonetic notation. I suppose some might hold that as an unassimilated loanword,  it’s “supposed” to be written with its original acute accent mark on the *é* to indicate the /e/ phonetics as otherwise you can’t know how to pronounce it.

Comment: Where are you getting the idea of pronouncing it with a K sound in English from?  German?  The name is French.  The French pronounce it with what's an SH sound in English.  In English, I've only heard it pronounced with English's SH sound, not its K sound.  Oh, and @tchrist, before you go and tell me what I can't do, note that I can because I just did, and everyone understood, including you.

Comment: @Recuvan What does “the English (incorrect) pronunciation” mean? Do you mean that English is incorrect, or do you mean the British who are not Welsh or Scots?

Comment: @tchrist I would normally agree about phonetic notation but as the question is simply about ‘sh’ vs ‘k’ it seems unnecessary to use a notation that many may not be familiar with. Those needing the IPA representation can fund it on the Wikipedia page and elsewhere.

Comment: Greek wife. We always called it "Beck mall". Second or third generation, so her Greek was not great.

Comment: What do you mean by "the English way"? How can a pronunciation be "the English way" of saying *bechamel* if English speakers don't actually use it? In native English words, the digraph "ch" usually represents the affricate /tʃ/, as in the word "beach".

Comment: AmEng speaker on YouTube https://youtu.be/Vsxbuh1s-g0?t=10s

Comment: BrEng speaker, Jamie Oliver, and his pronunciation https://youtu.be/SalyS66njMY?t=41s

Comment: As a Brit who is familiar with Jamie Oliver, I would hesitate to cite him as a pronunciation guide.

Answer (score 5):

According to [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/B%C3%A9chamel_sauce) it is pronounced with the **sh** sound in both English and French. So I don’t know where you get your k pronunciation from. I have never heard anyone (English or French) say that.

Answer (score 2):

I actually sometimes pronounce it becka-mel, too, despite having studied French. However, my American Webster's dictionary pronounces it bɛʃ'-ə-mɛl. The ch is coded the same as in *machine*, and the e is shown with the short e vowel sound (as in *best*). Also, in my dictionary the stress is on the first syllable. It comes across as: besh'-a-mel.

Comment: I'll use the one that doesn't require a subscription. However, the phonetic notation used in my c.1959 Dictionary (unavailable online) is a little different, although it means exactly the same thing -- so in light of that would I also be allowed to post *images* of the relevant information I found there? I hesitated in my answer this time, because some people have expressed their displeasure with pictures of my dictionary pages by arbitrarily editing them out of my answers, and I'd rather avoid future power struggles if at all possible.

Comment: I wouldn't use pictures. OED has Brit. /beɪʃəˈmɛl/, /bɛʃəˈmɛl/,  U.S. /ˌbeɪʃəˈmɛl/, /ˌbɛʃəˈmɛl/. The French pronunciation has no stresses: just /beʃəmɛl/. Many speakers in English just have /beʃəˈmɛl/ because they have monophthongs.

Comment: @tchrist: When the French pronounce béchamel by itself (not in a phrase), the stress is on the last syllable. This can change in connected speech, but this is why the English pronunciations have the stress on the last syllable.